# Error in using Arduino virtual wire

Tags: arduino, rf, communication

I have [this 433MHz RF Tx and Rx pair](http://www.ebay.com/itm/261041100836?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_2665wt_1503). I tried to transmit using following simple Arduino sketch, given in the [VirtualWire manual](http://www.open.com.au/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire.pdf).

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
  vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{
  const char *msg = "hello";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
  delay(400);
}
```

I've installed `VirtualWire Library` properly (it's there in `Sketch -> import Library`). But Arduino IDE gives following errors when trying to verify. It says **'vw_setup' was not declared in this scope**

```
In file included from sketch_sep08a.cpp:1:
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:59: error: variable or field 'vw_set_tx_pin' declared void
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:59: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:63: error: variable or field 'vw_set_rx_pin' declared void
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:63: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:67: error: variable or field 'vw_set_ptt_pin' declared void
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:67: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:71: error: variable or field 'vw_set_ptt_inverted' declared void
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:71: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:76: error: variable or field 'vw_setup' declared void
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:76: error: 'uint16_t' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:90: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:98: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:104: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:107: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\LordXaX\Documents\Arduino\libraries\VirtualWire/VirtualWire.h:112: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
sketch_sep08a.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
sketch_sep08a:3: error: 'vw_setup' was not declared in this scope
sketch_sep08a.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_sep08a:9: error: 'vw_send' was not declared in this scope
```

Why is that. How to fix this?

---

This is the content of imported `VirtualWire.h`

```
// VirtualWire.h
//
// Virtual Wire implementation for Arduino
// See the README file in this directory fdor documentation
// 
// Author: Mike McCauley (mikem@open.com.au)
// Copyright (C) 2008 Mike McCauley
// $Id: VirtualWire.h,v 1.3 2009/03/30 00:07:24 mikem Exp $

#ifndef VirtualWire_h
#define VirtualWire_h

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiring.h>

// These defs cause trouble on some versions of Arduino
#undef abs
#undef double
#undef round

// Maximum number of bytes in a message, counting the byte count and FCS
#define VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN 30

// The maximum payload length
#define VW_MAX_PAYLOAD VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN-3

// The size of the receiver ramp. Ramp wraps modulu this number
#define VW_RX_RAMP_LEN 160

// Number of samples per bit
#define VW_RX_SAMPLES_PER_BIT 8

// Ramp adjustment parameters
// Standard is if a transition occurs before VW_RAMP_TRANSITION (80) in the ramp,
// the ramp is retarded by adding VW_RAMP_INC_RETARD (11)
// else by adding VW_RAMP_INC_ADVANCE (29)
// If there is no transition it is adjusted by VW_RAMP_INC (20)
#define VW_RAMP_INC (VW_RX_RAMP_LEN/VW_RX_SAMPLES_PER_BIT)
#define VW_RAMP_TRANSITION VW_RX_RAMP_LEN/2
#define VW_RAMP_ADJUST 9
#define VW_RAMP_INC_RETARD (VW_RAMP_INC-VW_RAMP_ADJUST)
#define VW_RAMP_INC_ADVANCE (VW_RAMP_INC+VW_RAMP_ADJUST)

// Outgoing message bits grouped as 6-bit words
// 36 alternating 1/0 bits, followed by 12 bits of start symbol
// Followed immediately by the 4-6 bit encoded byte count, 
// message buffer and 2 byte FCS
// Each byte from the byte count on is translated into 2x6-bit words
// Caution, each symbol is transmitted LSBit first, 
// but each byte is transmitted high nybble first
#define VW_HEADER_LEN 8

// Cant really do this as a real C++ class, since we need to have 
// an ISR
extern "C"
{
    // Set the digital IO pin to be for transmit data
    // Defaults to 12
    extern void vw_set_tx_pin(uint8_t pin);

    // Set the digital IO pin to be for receive data
    // Defaults to 11
    extern void vw_set_rx_pin(uint8_t pin);

    // Set the digital IO pin to enable the transmitter (press to talk)
    // Defaults to 10
    extern void vw_set_ptt_pin(uint8_t pin);

    // By default the PTT pin goes high when the transmitter is enabled.
    // This flag forces it low when the transmitter is enabled.
    extern void vw_set_ptt_inverted(uint8_t inverted);

    // Initialise the VirtualWire software, to operate at speed bits per second
    // Call this one in your setup() after any vw_set_* calls
    // Must call vw_rx_start() before you will get any messages
    extern void vw_setup(uint16_t speed);

    // Start the Phase Locked Loop listening to the receiver
    // Must do this before you can receive any messages
    // When a message is available (good checksum or not), vw_have_message();
    // will return true.
    extern void vw_rx_start();

    // Stop the Phase Locked Loop listening to the receiver
    // No messages will be received until vw_rx_start() is called again
    // Saves interrupt processing cycles
    extern void vw_rx_stop();

    // Return true if the transmitter is active
    extern uint8_t vx_tx_active();

    // Block until the transmitter is idle
    extern void vw_wait_tx();

    // Block until a message is available
    extern void vw_wait_rx();
    // or for a max time
    extern uint8_t vw_wait_rx_max(unsigned long milliseconds);

    // Send a message with the given length. Returns almost immediately,
    // and message will be sent at the right timing by interrupts
    // Returns true if the message was accepted for transmissions
    // Returns false if the message is too long (>VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN - 3)
    extern uint8_t vw_send(uint8_t* buf, uint8_t len);

    // Returns true if an unread message is available
    extern uint8_t vw_have_message();

    // If a message is available (good checksum or not), copies
    // up to *len octets to buf.
    // Returns true if there was a message and the checksum was good
    extern uint8_t vw_get_message(uint8_t* buf, uint8_t* len);
}

#endif
```

Comment: This is very likely due to incompatibility of the library for Arduino 1.0 vs older version, so you'll need to include the version-specific header files that the library uses. Try this: Open VirtualWire.h and look at the top few lines: You probably see stdlib.h, wiring.h, etc... Reply here with a list of which *.h (header files) you see are included.

Comment: @boardbite please see the edited post. I've added whole `VirtualWire.h` content. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot @boardbite You were right!!! I downloaded v1.5. But after what you said I searched and installed latest version, 1.9. It works!!! many thanks!!!

Comment: For your future reference, if there is a library that uses Wiring.h, WProgram.h, etc., you can also use the method outlined in my Answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure the Arduino VERSION-specific header files that the library needs to use are in fact included. So you can either download the latest version of the library -- perhaps they've already adapted it for the new Arduino version -- or alternatively, you can try this:

At the top of VirtualWire.h, replace:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiring.h>
```

with this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#if ARDUINO < 100
#include <wiring.h>
#else
#include <Arduino.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! [this is the version 1.9](http://www.open.com.au/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire/VirtualWire-1.9.zip). Hope that'll help some one (like me :D)...